# Constructors in Abstract Classes?

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Abstract class constructor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/abstract-class-constructor-in-java)

When we can't create an instance of abstract class, what is the purpose of a constructor?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/abstract-class-constructor-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still extend the abstract class and call the abstracts class' constructor in your derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I often create a constructor with some parameters (and don't create empty constructor) in abstract class and in this way I make all subclasses to have constructor with all these parameters. This approach guarantees that subclasses are initialized correctly.

But in my last few projects I use spring with its dependency injection for this purpose.