# what is constructor call when child class of abstract class is instantiated.?

Tags: inheritance, constructor, abstract-class, call, instantiation

can anyone tell me what is what is the constructor call when I am inheriting a abstract class and then I instantiate a child class.

eg.

```
public abstract class AbsParentClass
{
//having some functions.
} 

public class ChildClass : AbsParentClass
{
//having functions that over ride the functions of abstract class.
}
```

now If I do this

```
ChildClass objchild = new ChildClass();
```

then what would be the constructor calls ?

my confusion is abstract can not be instantiated , 
but when we inherit a class and instantiate a child class then base class is also instantiated, so how is this scenario handle in case of abstract classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can an abstract class have a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/abstract-class-constructor-in-java)