# When/how do i initialize static members of an abstract class ? (no lazy loading)

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that is somewhat like a View from Android. I create a lot of classes that extend it to draw different stuff. Now i would like all those classes to share the same Paints so that colors match and so on.

My ideas would be

- pass some context or windowmetrics to every single constructor, but that feels silly as i only need it once.
- i could add a static method init() to the abstract class, but i try to avoid public static methods.
- create a subclass with the single purpose to set the static members of the superclass and also null them at the end, something like a remote control to the superclass' static stuff.

im just not sure what risks there are or if there are even simpler ways to do it.

Edit:
to init the static members i need a context (for those not familiar with android) and that context needs to be passed to that class, so no init in static blocks etc

Comment: Why do you need a static method in the abstract class for you purpose? In the constructor of the abstract class you can write the common logic to all the extending classes. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/261159/572830

Comment: I think you should look at defining your own custom Views or Styles, and then inherit from them

Comment: @TanjaV the problem remains, i have to pass some info at runtime to do final size calculations and that info i would like to share as static between all classes that inherit my base class

Comment: I dont really understand what youre trying to do. If you want to match colors, define the colors in an XML resource file

Comment: what i want to do is adapt textsizes at runtime to match the screen resolution, in XML you can only define DP or SP but no %-Pixels and weight cannot be applied to textsize.

Answer (score 0):

Or just add a static block and initialize them there:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public static final int DEFAULT_PAINTS_SIZE = 5;
    public static Paint [] paints;

    static {
        paints = new Paints[DEFAULT_PAINTS_SIZE];
        // initialize the values somehow.
    }
}
```

Comment: some settings are not available at startup so the static block would not have all the infos needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize them directly:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyStatic myStaticObject = new MyStatic();
}
```

or in a static initializer block:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyStatic myStaticObject;
    static {
        //something = stuff
        myStaticObject = new MyStatic(something);
        //more stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: some settings are not available at startup so the static block would not have all the infos needed.

Comment: Then initialize it when the info is available; it is legal to initialize static fields in instance methods.

Comment: could you give me a short example of this ?