# "Cannot instantiate the type...."

Tags: java

```
public class TestingClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numberRooms = 6;
        double totalSpace;
        Room[] rooms = new Room[numberRooms];
        rooms[0] = new Room(20, 20);
        rooms[1] = new Room(20, 20);
        rooms[2] = new Room(22, 20);
        rooms[3] = new Room(20, 20);
        rooms[4] = new Room(25, 20);
        rooms[5] = new Room(15, 13);

         Garage garage = new Garage(20, "Cement", 1, 20, 1, 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberRooms; i++) {
            totalSpace = totalSpace + calculateRoomSpace(rooms[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Total room space is " + totalSpace);

        foo(garage);

    }

    public static double calculateRoomSpace(Room roomSpace) {
        double newRoomSpace = roomSpace.calcFloorSpace();
        return newRoomSpace;
    }

    public static void foo(Building myBuilding) {
        System.out.println("Total floor space is " + myBuilding.calcFloorSpace());
    }
}
```

I put in this code and get the error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot instantiate the type Garage

    at TestingClass.main(TestingClass.java:17)"
```

what is the problem here exactly?

*Edit*
** Here is the Garage class**

```
abstract public class Garage extends Building {


    private int cars;
    private String floorType;
    private int garageLength;
    private int garageWidth;

    public Garage(int floors, int windows, int cars, String floorType,
            int garageLength, int garageWidth) {
        super(floors, windows);
        this.cars = cars;
        this.floorType = floorType;
        this.garageLength = garageLength;
        this.garageWidth = garageWidth;
    }

    @Override
public double calcFloorSpace() {
    int floorSize;
    floorSize = garageLength * garageWidth;
    return floorSize;
}

    public int getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(int cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public String getFloorType() {
        return floorType;
    }

    public void setFloorType(String floorType) {
        this.floorType = floorType;
    }

    public int getGarageLength() {
        return garageLength;
    }

    public void setGarageLength(int garageLength) {
        this.garageLength = garageLength;
    }

    public int getGarageWidth() {
        return garageWidth;
    }

    public void setGarageWidth(int garageWidth) {
        this.garageWidth = garageWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Garage [cars=" + cars + ", floorType=" + floorType
                + ", garageLength=" + garageLength + ", garageWidth="
                + garageWidth + "]";
    }

}
```

Hope this helps. Not an expert at this and have spent quite a while figuring this out. thanks

Comment: How does your `Garage` class look like?

Comment: Where is your garage Class?

Comment: Is `Garage` outside of `TestingClass`' directory? If so, you need to `import` it.

Comment: Is `Garage` an abstract class?

Comment: Seems like @MikeSamuel

Comment: @MikeSamuel According to the latest update from OP, it is.

Comment: @Nargis just added the garage class guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't instantiate an abstract class.

You've got two options:

- Remove `abstract` from the class declaration, or
- Create another class to extend `Garage`, which can be instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate an instance of an `abstract` class. You either need to make your class concrete (remove the `abstract` modifier on the class and provide an implementation for all methods), or extend the abstract class to create a non-abstract class.

When you remove the `abstract` modifier, the compiler will tell you what abstract methods you are missing (if any).

Answer (score 2):

Your Garage Class is declared as abstract class cannot be instantiated .Check this for more details [Can an abstract class have a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/can-an-abstract-class-have-a-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Garage is an abstract class, so it cannot be instantiated. Only its subclasses can be instantiated.