# When a class extends from an abstract class then how to access its private variables?

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `A` and class `B` extends from it.I made those variables private and its fine.

```
public abstract class A  {
    private String name;
    private String location;

public A(String name,String location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
}
 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
```

Then I want to write the class B.

```
public class B extends A{
private int fee;
private int goals;   // something unique to class B
```

I don't understand how to write a constructor for class B  to access it's private variables.
   I wrote something like this and its wrong.

```
    B(int fee, int goals){
       this.fee= fee;
       this.goals=goals;
     }
```

Can u help me to solve this with a short explanation.

Comment: The error message explains what the problem is. Read it.

Comment: its not wrong, the problem because you need to construct your parent class first before you can construct your B class, so you need to call super(name, location) on B constructor to construct the parent first.

Comment: [As there is no default (or no-arg) constructor in the parent abstract class the constructor used in subclasses must be specified.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/260755/2830834)

Comment: Thanks Friends for the help :) now i understood it very well

Comment: @SanukaHasith You can say your thanks by voting up :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above should be fine, except that you have to specify a call to `A`'s constructor, since by constructing a `B`, you're *also* constructing an `A`

e.g

```
public B(int fee, int goals) {
    super(someName, someLocation); // this is calling A's constructor
    this.fee= fee;
    this.goals=goals;
}
```

In the above you somehow have to determine how to construct an `A`. What values will you specify for `A` ? You would normally pass that into the constructor for B e.g.

```
public B(int fee, int goals, String name, String location) {
    super(name, location);
    this.fee= fee;
    this.goals=goals;
}
```

Comment: thanks Brian now i understood it and now it works fine.Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a default constructor for class `A`. It means you must specifies a call to `A` constructor from `B` constructor.

```
public B(String name, String location int fee, int goals) {
    super(name, location); // this line call the superclass constructor
    this.fee = fee;
    this.goals = goals;
}
```

If a class inherit another, when you construct the child Class an implicit call to the mother class constructor is also done.
Since your `A` does not have default constructor, it means you want to use a specific one, so you must call it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony now i got it.