# Why aren't abstract constructors allowed?

Tags: java

I'm making an abstract `Font` class and I want to force subclasses to declare a constructor that takes a single `int` parameter (font size). I tried doing so as follows.

```
public abstract class Font {
  ...
  public abstract Font(int size);
  ...
}
```

But my compiler declares:

```
Error:(20, 19) java: <path omitted>/Font.java:20: modifier abstract not allowed here
```

This isn't exactly the end of the world - this isn't strictly necessary, I just wanted the Java compiler to force me to remember to implement that constructor. I just wonder why this isn't allowed?

Comment: This feature doesn't seem like a good idea.  Say you have a concrete class that defines another private field `f` that must be initialized to some useful value, so all the concrete class constructors should have a value to store into `f`.  Do you really want the compiler complaining because none of your constructors have the profile `(int size)`?

Comment: Constructors can't be overridden (they are always non-virtual against a concrete type). As to why this feature doesn't exist - well, if it did then that would be a different language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any constructor you create must be called by any class that implements this abstract class, so there's not really a need to "remind" people to implement that constructor.

There are a lot of reasons that people extending your classes might want to create their own constructors. For example:

```
public MySpecialSize16Font()
{
    super(16);
}
```

or

```
public ColoredFont(int size, Color color)
{
    super(size);
    this.color = color;
}
```

It's not really your place to specify what constructors these classes can and cannot provide.

Comment: In my case I already have a constructor for the `Font` class, but I want to be forced to implement both.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: That violates the open/closed principle. As long as child classes can provide the parent with everything it needs to be instantiated, why should you care whether a specific constructor is implemented? They should be able to create whatever constructors they want.

Comment: Fair enough, I see your point. I'll just have to keep track of my own conventions then.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: Yeah, if you're thinking of this in terms of coding conventions, you might be able to enforce this with advanced style checker rules.

Comment: Side note, I see you use the syntax `base(...)` to call a superclass' constructor. Is that legal? I've always used `super(...)`.

Comment: @anthropomorphic it isn't valid syntax, the answerer means `super(...)`. `base` is just saying that it means the base constructor.

Comment: Thanks for that correction. I've been too long in C# land.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement that constructor in the abstract class, at least at a trivial level (perhaps with no error checking), give it protected access, and make that `size` variable be only settable through it--that would effectively enforce its use by sub-classes, assuming that `size` is an important attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout this: [Can an abstract class have a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/can-an-abstract-class-have-a-constructor)

Try to remove the abstract @ your constructor.
It should be:

```
public Font(int size);
```

Should work then if im not mistaken :)

Comment: No, it doesn't work, and you are mistaken. You cannot just leave a constructor with a semicolon, you must implement it. This does not compile.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Oh yes, you're right, I didn't look closely enough. LOLWTF, yes, it does look like you are mistaken.