# How do I augment the constructor of a child class?

Tags: java, android

I have a class that extends another class. I need to run additional code in the constructor of my child class. How do I do this?

```
//MyClass.class
//This is what i want to do
public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super(); // EDIT (thanks)
        // stuff?
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: It's just `super();`.

Comment: First of all, it's `super()`.

Comment: Thanks, i edited :). How do i augment though?

Answer (score 2):

should be:

```
/MyClass.class
//This is what i want to do
public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    MyClass() {
        super(); // no need for constructor here, just super()
        // stuff?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `super()`. This will call the super class's constructor. See [Can an abstract class have a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/can-an-abstract-class-have-a-constructor)

Comment: How do I add to the constructor?

Comment: Just add the new code in place of the `// stuff` line.