# If constructor not build the object what is used to make the object?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

According to this [Can an abstract class have a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/can-an-abstract-class-have-a-constructor?answertab=active#tab-top)
the **constructor** does not **build** the object and it is used to initialize fields so what is used to build the object?
As in **abstract class**  the constructor exists and it's not allowed to make an instance from that class and only could inherit it.
 so the question is

> What really builds the object in java ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an abstract class have a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/can-an-abstract-class-have-a-constructor)

Comment: An abstract class cannot be instantiated by definition; it's always a concrete class (anonymous or named) that gets created.

Answer (score 3):

An instance of an object in Java is created every time you use the **new** keyword. For example,

```
MyClass myObject1 = new MyClass("John", 1, 1000.20);
MyClass myObject2 = new MyClass("Mary", 2, 200);
MyClass myObject3 = new MyClass();
```

However, you can only instantiate a **concrete** class and *never* a **abstract** class. So a question arises, what's the point in having an abstract class?

You have a **abstract** class to provide a common set of functionalities which can be shared by all its **subclasses**, e.g., attributes, fields, etc.

And of course, an abstract can have a constructor. If you don't provide a constructor explicitly, it will have a *default constructor*. Whenever one of its concrete subclasses is instantiated, the constructor of the subclass will call the super constructor before doing any type of work in its own constructor. For example,

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
   private String name;

   private int age;

   public MyAbstractClass() {
       name = "bozo";
       age = 5;
   }

  public MyAbstractClass(String name, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
  }
  ...
}

public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    private double income;

    public MyClass() {
        //calls super() implicitly.
    }

    public MyClass(String name, int age, double income) {
        //calls super explicitly
        super(name, age);
        this.income = income;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Constructor is mandatory for any class.**

All classes (abstract like concrete) have to declare a constructor.
It may be a generated no arg constructor or a explicitly declared constructor but anyway, the constructor presence is mandatory.
Why ?
Because for any class that inherits from a class (that is : all classes but `Object`), the first statement of any invoked constructor is invoking the direct parent constructor, that may at its turn invoke its parent constructor, and so on.

**Use the `new` operator to create an instance**

As you want to create an instance of a specific class, you have to invoke the constructor of its class by prefixing it with the `new` operator :

```
new MyObject();
```

But it makes sense only for concrete classes.

**Indeed, abstract classes cannot be instantiated**

So, the constructor of the abstract class will be used but only as you create an instance of a child class (whatever its level in the hierarchy) of this abstract class (what I explained in the first point).

Suppose `Child` is concrete and `Parent` is abstract, you **have to** invoke the parent constructor of `Child` in the `Child` constructor :

```
 Child(){super();}
```

But you will never invoke `new Parent()` as it is not legal to instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: It is noticeable that English isn't your first language, and sometimes "funny" grammar kicks in ... but I think the technical content is fine.

Comment: You are always fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The new Operator does build the Object indeed.

The reason why an abstract class always has a constructor (explicit or implicit) is because it is called from it's not abstract subclasses.