# Java - Not able to get value of Custom Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have a custom Annotation like this -

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ControllerAction {
    String value();
}
```

I have a class that uses this annotation like this -

```
public class TestController extends AbstractController {

    public TestController () {
        super();
    }

    @ControllerAction("add")
    public void addCandidate(){

    }

}
```

The super class looks like this -

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    public AbstractController (){

    }

    public CustomBean processRequest(ServletAction action, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Class<AbstractController > controllerClass = AbstractController.class;
        for (Method method : controllerClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ControllerAction.class)) {
                Annotation annotation = (ControllerAction) method.getAnnotation(ControllerAction.class);
                if(annotation != null){
                    if(annotation.value().equals(action.getAction())){
                        method.invoke(controllerClass.newInstance());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `processRequest(...)` method in `AbstractController` is called from a servlet directly. The processRequest() method figures out the servlet action, and based on that, it should call the method appropriately.
For example, if the `ServletAction.getAction() == 'add'`, `processRequest()` should automatically call `addCandidate()` in `TestController`. But I am not able to get the value of the Annotation. Somehow `annotation.value()` is giving a compilation error in eclipse. Eclipse is not showing any method I can use to get the annotation value.

I want to know if there is a way to get value() of the Custom Annotation. I dont want to define my Annotation with anything else other than `String value()`. I want to know if it is possible to achieve what I want with just `String value()` in my custom Annotation?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why does the abstract class have constructor?

Comment: Its my bad. This code is work in progress. I thought that I might need some processing done while initializing, but it can be removed if not needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/can-an-abstract-class-have-a-constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to change

```
Annotation annotation = (ControllerAction) method.getAnnotation(ControllerAction.class);
```

To

```
ControllerAction annotation = method.getAnnotation(ControllerAction.class);
```

Otherwise the methods specific to `ControllerAction` will not be known to the compiler as `annotation` is of type `Annotation`

Additionally - as pointed out by Sharon Ben Asher - instead of `AbstractController.class` you should use `getClass()` to get the class of the actual implementation at runtime. Given the current code only the methods of `AbstractController` will be checked but not the ones of implementing classes.

Comment: Why do you need to cast? This `ControllerAction annotation = method.getAnnotation(ControllerAction.class);` should be enough.

Comment: I have another question. How is above code efficiency wise? What If I have a lot of methods? Is Java reflection suggested where efficiency a concern?

Comment: @john: That is needed, so that compiler know the type and calls appropriate methods instead. The arument on RHS will just give an object of type ControllerAction, which is also of type Annotation.

Comment: ok, this is how `getAnnotation()` looks like inside : `return annotationClass.cast(declaredAnnotations().get(annotationClass));` the casting is already there. I had to check sources for that, so again : why do you need to cast ?)

Comment: I have to say I do not understand how this works for you.  The code examines the methods of `AbstractController` so how is it able to detect a method from a subclass ??

Comment: [`getAnnotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) is a generic method, so what @john is saying is right. The cast is pointless.

Comment: Of course the cast is not needed due to the greatness of Java‘s generics. Additionally instead of `AbstractController.class` simply `getClass()` should be used to get the class of the actual implementation.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher you’re absolutely right. I only spotted the obvious error in the casting first. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @dpr: Okay. I am not so godd with Reflection. So how do I make sure that the methods of only implementing subclass are checked.

Comment: @john: Agreed. I was wrong earlier. No need for another casting. I thought you were talking about LHS of assignment operator. My bad.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher: Okay, so I am not so good with reflection. Can you please tell me how I would check methods of implementing subclasses? Idea is that concrete classes will be using the annotation. Abstract class "processRequest" will call appropriate method according to value of annotation.

Comment: just use `this.getClass()` the current object is of type of the concrete implementation