# Since an abstract class can have a public constructor, why can't we instantiate it?

Tags: java, constructor, singleton, abstract-class, instantiation

I know a singleton class cannot be instantiated because it has a private constructor. I would assume the same for an abstract class, but it can contain an public constructor, so why can we not instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: This has nothing to do with constructors. Abstract classes can't be instantiated because they are abstract... Maybe a better question is "Why can abstract classes have constructors?", which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/can-an-abstract-class-have-a-constructor).

Comment: But I want to understand what property is making abstract classes un-instantiable, I know for singletons its because their constructor is private

Comment: It's "by definition". [The spec says so, thus it is so](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1).

Comment: Maybe take some time to read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have constructed a small example to answer 2 questions

### 1. Why one might need a public constructor inside an abstract class?

Assume you have an abstract class `Animal` which is inherited by classes `Dog` & `Monkey` (We can add many child classes like this)

```java
abstract class Animal {
    int legs;

    public Animal(int legs) {
        this.legs = legs;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(int legs) {
        super(legs);
    }
}
class Monkey extends Animal {
    public Monkey(int legs){
        super(legs); 
    }
}
```

Now if we create a `Dog` object and call its constructor it will in return call the constructor of `Animal` class and update int `legs`. If you observe we can now use the constructor of `Animal` class and use it to update the value of an N number of classes which inherit it. So one might use a public constructor inside an abstract class.

### 2. Why can't we instantiate the object of an abstract class? [source](http://net-informations.com/faq/oops/abstr.htm#:%7E:text=No%2C%20you%20cannot%20create%20an,before%20you%20can%20use%20it.)

> You cannot create an instance of an abstract class because it does not have a complete implementation. The purpose of an abstract class is to function as a base for subclasses. It acts like a template, or an empty or partially empty structure, you should extend it and build on it before you can use it.

Here is a little modification to our example

```java
abstract class Animal {
    int legs;
    String ability;

    public Animal(int legs) {
        this.legs = legs;
    }

    abstract void showAbility();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(int legs) {
        super(legs);
    }
    public void showAbility() {
        System.out.println("Sniff");
    }
}
class Monkey extends Animal {
    public Monkey(int legs){
        super(legs); 
    }
    public void showAbility() {
        System.out.println("Climb");
    }
}
```

Now assume if you were able to create an object like `new Animal()` then will `new Animal().showAbility()` had a meaning? No! because it does not have a complete implementation. I believe this is a good reason why objects of abstract classes can't be instantiated.